# Text box like search bar in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, textbox

is there any way to create a text input just like [search bar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/search/) for Jquery Mobile. For example when we type text there should be a cross mark which allows users to clear the field.

Even if I to use search bar as input field there is a search icon showing up and it doesn't seem nice and appropritate for a textbox.

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.The idea is to hide the icon in the search input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .content .ui-icon-searchfield::after{
        display:none !important;
    }

    .content .ui-input-search{
        padding:0 10px !important;
    }

    </style>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <input type="search" name="search" id="searc-basic" value="" />     
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/8sg6M/

Answer (score 3):

Add data-clear-btn="true" to your input TextBox